# Android App Crash By Using Android in app Marketing Feature

Tags: android, android-intent, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to use Andriod in app billing feature in our Flex App. I have downloaded the sample code from android developer forum from following URL

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html

and follow all the instructions give on this. But when I export the build in release (as instructed in http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html) and install it on my device the app get crashed, every time I try to open the its get crashed.

If I run the same app in debug mod I get message that

> This version of the application is not configured for billing.

I am new in Android development I want to use in app feature in our Flex based Android app. Can someone help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First check your AndroidManifest.xml file to see if you put the permissions for billing service, just like the sample shows, don't forget the service needs to be inside the aplication tag

About the crash, you need to give more details, check your logcat

Answer (score 0):

add into your AndroidManifest.xml the permission::

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```